# Flex datagrid tab to checkbox column

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, checkbox, tabs

Context: I have a data grid where the following has been implemented. tabbing through each column in a single row and creating a new row when tabbing from the last column.

The last column in my datagrid is now a checkbox. I set the 'editable' to false as shown below (since we don't want editable text to be shown when user clicks on/tabs to checkbox.

Problem: When I tab through the columns of a given row, I cannot tab to the checkbox column and therefore cannot use the space bar to toggle between checked/unchecked. The user is forced to use the mouse to toggle the check box.

Question: How do I let user tab to the checkbox column, and press spacebar to toggle between checked and unchecked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can override the selected property for the checkbox

```
override public set selected(value:Boolean):void
{
    // check for spacebar or click
}
```